# Using button in UpdatePanel in content page does not trigger click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one site master page and one content page. Whenever I click button in content page it is not triggering click event method to execute.

SiteMaster Code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body background="../../Content/city-balcony@2x.jpg">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Welcome to E-Meeting</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
            </div> 

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                                <%
                                    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                                    {
                                %>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Chat", "ViewPage1")%></li>
                                <% }
                                %>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <%="Last communicated at : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()%>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Content Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Modified by click event";
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    ChT
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>ChT</h2>
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />        
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="On Load"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>


    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

Whenever I click button I want label text to be "Modified by click event"  but it remains same "On Load". Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a trigger in your update panel as shown:

```
</ContentTemplate> 
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />        
</Triggers>
```

And Check ScriptManager's ***`EnablePartialRendering`*** and remove it if it presented or set it to **`true`**

Comment: Not working. To verify I have added protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {Label1.Text = "Modified by page load"; } while debugging cursor is going there but label text is still not getting modified.

Comment: After setting UpdateMode="Conditional" for UpdatePanel the label1.text always displays "Modified by page load" but text is not getting updated from click event

Comment: Have you added ajax control toolkit? If so try to add this in ur page load event using AjaxControlToolkit; and use UpdateMode="Always"

Answer (score 0):

you can add a method using C# to trigger the event.

1. double-click button to create a button click event.
2. add a code to change the label text to "Modified by click event"

for example,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)｛

Label1.text = "Modified by click event";

｝
```

by the way, you could get rid of Text="On Load" in your aspx code. (your code would be: `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>`, then add a page_load method in your .cs file:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
      Label1.text = "On load";

    }
```

in this case, it will display "on load" when you open the webpage, and it will display "Modified by click event" when you clicked button.

hope it